# Run shortcode before filters

Tags: theme-development, filters, shortcode

My users post snippets code in comments.
I created a shortcode for this :

```
function post_codigo($atts,$content=""){

        return '<code>'.$content.'</code>';
}

add_shortcode('codigo','post_codigo');
```

Problem is that html gets filtered before its wrapped into the code tags.

I think that if i can get the shortcode run before filters then i can use

```
function pre_esc_html($content) {
  return preg_replace_callback(
    '#(<code.*?>)(.*?)(</code>)#imsu',
    create_function(
      '$i',
      'return $i[1].esc_html($i[2]).$i[3];'
    ),
    $content
  );
}

add_filter(
  'the_content',
  'pre_esc_html',
  9
);
```

that i found around here. What you think?

UPDATED: Ok now i changed my shortcode to:

```
 function post_codigo($atts,$content=""){

            return '<code>'.esc_html($content).'</code>';
    }

    add_shortcode('codigo','post_codigo');
```

But it still adding

breaks and breaking the whole code into several  tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the array **$no_texturize_shortcodes**, which is a collection of shortcodes that are excluded from wptexturize. If you do this, everything within `[codigo]` shortcode tags will not be texturized:

```
add_filter( 'no_texturize_shortcodes', 'no_texturize_codigo_shortcode' );

function no_texturize_codigo_shortcode( $excluded_shortcodes ) {
    $excluded_shortcodes[] = 'codigo';
    return $excluded_shortcodes;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but im getting same result. If you check source of http://masquewordpress.com/ayuda/como-cargar-correctamente-wordpress-en-un-script-no-wp-para-la-solicitud-de-ajax#comment-24 you will see that javascript is still as javascript. I need to scape all text in my shortcode function?

Comment: I escaped my shortcode now but still acting funny. I updated my question

Comment: hmmm. I don't really see it. It seems to look OK to me. Are you still having issues with it?

Comment: Nope, i only changed the <code> tag to <pre> and the problem solved. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The `no_texturize_shortcodes` filter did nothing for me, as the content inside the shortcode would have already been filtered by `wpautop()` and any other filters hooked to the `the_content`. I resorted to changing the filter order of `do_shortcode` in relation to `the_content`, so that I can be certain it runs first of the two. Here's how:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11); // AFTER wpautop()
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 9); // BEFORE wpautop()
```

This seems to work out fairly well, but as this is quite an extensive alteration to the way WordPress handles its text/html conversion I'd recommend you use it with caution. The more plugins/shortcodes you are using the more likely you are to run in to trouble relating to this change I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

Is your theme using [`comment_text()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_text)  to display your visitor's comments?

if so try changing:

```
<?php comment_text(); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(apply_filters('comment_text', get_comment_text())); ?>
```

This will apply any "comment_text" filters to the comment text, **before** it will apply the shortcode.

This should be done in your theme templates wherever comments are displayed.

Comment: Thanks but i need the other way around. The shortcode should run before filter so then i can avoid filtering inside the shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use html chars?

```
return '&lt;code&gt;'.$content.'&lt;/code&gt;';
```

.
Tried this localy and it works gr8